# 404 Not Found nodejs to localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing nodejs express to fetch the data to web page. an error appear 404 Not Found when open

> http://127.0.0.1:3000/users

in the Dev tool on the browser show: **users:1          GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/users 404 (Not Found)**

below are the app.js and index.js and users.js files

I think I have an issue with the routes

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 var logger = require('morgan');
 var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
 var flash = require('express-flash');
 var session = require('express-session');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 
 var mysql = require('mssql');
//  var connection  = require('./lib/db');
 
 var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
 var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
 
 var app = express();
 
// view engine setup
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 
 app.use(logger('dev'));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 //I put false instead true
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 
 app.use(session({ 
     secret: '123456cat',
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true,
     cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
 }))
 
 app.use(flash());
 app.use(expressValidator());

 app.use('/', indexRouter);
 app.use('/list', usersRouter);
 
 
 // catch 404 and forward to error handler
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   next(createError(404));
 });
 
 // error handler
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   // set locals, only providing error in development
   res.locals.message = err.message;
   res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
 // render the error page
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error');
 });

 module.exports = app;
```

below are the routes files.
**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection  = require('../database.js');
 
 
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM users',function(err,rows)     {
 
        if(err){
         req.flash('error', err); 
         res.render('list',{page_title:"Users - Node.js",data:''});   
        }else{
            
            res.render('list',{page_title:"Users - Node.js",data:rows});
        }
                            
         });
        
    });
 
 
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You don't have a user route therefore you will get a 404 not found error. You wrote `/list` as route for `routes/users.js`.

Comment: @kmp Please make your comment as an answer. It will give the ability to Fahd to accepted as useful/correct. This will help others too.

Comment: I found the answer, change the code to  app.use('/user', usersRouter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment, you don't have a `/user` route therefore you will get a *404 NotFound* error.

Change this

```
app.use('/list', usersRouter);
```

To this

```
app.use('/user', usersRouter);
```